# What is the precedence in autotools user variables?

Tags: autotools

If you have a project with a configure.ac and many Makefile.am files, it is possible to pass a user variable such as CFLAGS to configure as

CFLAGS=DEBUG_OPTIONS ./configure

But, if inside configure.ac, you have a statement like
CFLAGS=NON_DEBUG_OPTIONS (you can assume this is coming after AC_PROG_CC)
will the final objects be debuggable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Autoconf's perspective, [`CFLAGS` is an *output variable*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Preset-Output-Variables.html#Preset-Output-Variables), just like those your configure.ac declares explicitly via the `AC_SUBST` macro.  The details of output variables are spread about a bit in the Autoconf documentation, but basically,

> [they] are shell variables whose values are substituted into files
>   that configure outputs.

([Autoconf manual, section 7.2](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#index-Output-variables-1201))

The `AC_PROG_CC` macro provides a default value for `CFLAGS` if that variable is not already set (*e.g.* from the environment); otherwise, it leaves the value unchanged.  This is why it is generally effective to specify `CFLAGS` and certain other output variables to Autoconf `configure` scripts on the command line in the way you show -- it is standard shell syntax that causes the variable binding to be placed in the environment of the command being run.

The manual goes on to say,

> [Being an output variable] means that `AC_OUTPUT` replaces instances of ‘`@variable@`’ in
>   input files with **the value that the shell variable `variable` has when
>   `AC_OUTPUT` is called**.

(Emphasis added.)  Although that's in the docs of the `AC_SUBST` macro, it applies to preset output variables the same as it does to those set via `AC_SUBST`.  Thus, if `configure` assigns a new value to `CFLAGS` before `AC_OUTPUT`, then the last such value assigned is the one that is substituted into your Makefiles.  In direct answer to your question, then, the situation you describe will result in a build with non-debug options.

Note also that this is not a precedence issue at all because there's only one variable involved.  The `CFLAGS` set in the environment is effectively *the same variable* that the `configure` script accesses and uses internally, that you can modify within via assignment, and that ultimately is substituted into your Makefiles.  Thus, it's a simple order of operations question.

Finally, I observe that your question arises at all only if you violate an Autotools principle regarding "user variables" such as `CFLAGS`.  The Autoconf docs for that variable put it this way:

> Sometimes package developers are tempted to set user variables such as
>   `CFLAGS` because it appears to make their job easier. However, **the
>   package itself should never set a user variable, *particularly not to
>   include switches that are required for proper compilation of the
>   package***. Since these variables are documented as being for the package
>   builder, that person rightfully expects to be able to override any of
>   these variables at build time. If the package developer needs to add
>   switches without interfering with the user, the proper way to do that
>   is to introduce an additional variable. Automake makes this easy by
>   introducing `AM_CFLAGS` (see Flag Variables Ordering), but the concept
>   is the same even if Automake is not used.

(Emphasis added.)

Extra finally, note that a user can always override an output variable or other make variable by setting a value on the `make` command line, as an argument to `make`, either instead of or in addition to specifying it to `configure`.

Comment: Thank you for this in depth delving of the subject matter. I have noted that you believe that CFLAGS is the same whether assigned inside or outside configure. But, like you said, CFLAGS inside configure substitutes @CFLAGS@ elsewhere; CLAGS outside is cached and invoked while doing
./conf.status --recheck
I wouldn't say the two are the same.

Comment: @zeb, you seem to have misunderstood me.  I said that the `CFLAGS` variable accessed inside `configure` is essentially the same *variable* as the one set outside, in that command's environment.  That is, there is not a separate variable of the same name inside `configure`, such that one could take precedence over the other.  That speaks to how to understand `configure`'s behavior with respect to that variable, but not directly to what *value* that variable has at any given point.

Comment: Just want to make sure that you realize that cached variables are stored in a different place. Eg. if you look in config.log, you can see that CFLAGS outside ./configure is stored in ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value.

Comment: @zeb, I know about and understand the Autoconf cache.  Among other things, it caches the *values* that `CFLAGS` and other "precious" variables have at the beginning of a `configure` run.  This particular aspect of the cache is primarily meant to support running child project `configure` scripts with an environment equivalent to the parent's initial one.  That is irrelevant to anything in my answer.  In particular, it does not create another variable named `CFLAGS` -- at most, it can be construed as creating a differently-named variable whose value is derived from `CFLAGS`'.